# Returning results as a promise in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

How can I make the below function to return a promise so that I can handle it properly in the Page that calls this function?

```
getUploads() {
    const rootDef = this.db.database.ref();
    const uploadsRef = rootDef.child('userUploads').orderByChild('time');
    const userRef = rootDef.child("userProfile");
    var uploads = [];

    uploadsRef.once("value").then((uploadSnaps) => {

      uploadSnaps.forEach((uploadSnap) => {

        var upload = uploadSnap.val();

        userRef.child(uploadSnap.val().user).once("value").then((userSnap) => {
          upload.displayName = userSnap.val().displayName;
          upload.avatar = userSnap.val().avatar;
          uploads.push(upload);
        });

      });

    });

    return uploads;
}
```

I tried the below, but it shows error. How should I modify?

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(uploads);
});
```

I will be calling this method as shown below.

```
this.db.getUploads().then((uploads) => {
  this.allUploads = uploads;
  console.log(this.allUploads);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could surround the **contents** of your method with

```
getUploads() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // content of method
        resolve(uploads); // instead of "return uploads"
    });
}
```

Comment: This would resolve to an empty array. The resolve has to be placed somewhere in the callbacks.

Comment: It works for me too. How it's different from my way of usage in returning promise?

Comment: I think because you don't include `uploadsRef.once("value").then((uploadSnaps) => { .. }`. The Promise will resolve before waiting for the `.then()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Promise.resolve](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve):

> The Promise.resolve(value) method returns a Promise object that is
>   resolved with the given value. If the value is a thenable (i.e. has a
>   "then" method), the returned promise will "follow" that thenable,
>   adopting its eventual state; otherwise the returned promise will be
>   fulfilled with the value.

So simply:

```
return Promise.resolve(uploads);
```

But the problem with your code is that you return the value before the `uploadsRef.once("value").then(...)` has been invoked.
You should simply return the result from `then`:

```
return uploadsRef.once("value").then((uploadSnaps) => {
    ...
    return uploads
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This should handle the asynchronous calls correctly and return all uploads:

```
getUploads() {
    const rootDef = this.db.database.ref();
    const uploadsRef = rootDef.child('userUploads').orderByChild('time');
    const userRef = rootDef.child("userProfile");

    return uploadsRef.once("value").then((uploadSnaps) => {

      return Promise.all(uploadSnaps.map(uploadSnap => {
        var upload = uploadSnap.val();

        return userRef.child(uploadSnap.val().user).once("value").then((userSnap) => {
          upload.displayName = userSnap.val().displayName;
          upload.avatar = userSnap.val().avatar;
          return upload;
        });        
      }));
    });
}
```

Comment: Where do we deal with uploads var?

Comment: `return uploadsRef.once("value").then((uploadSnaps) [...]` returns a Promise to an array that would be your uploads variable.